# Unintended behaviour when rebinding key in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

So, I've tried to map a key to a different command than default, but I don't get the desired effect.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<left>") (message "Use C-f!"))
```

As you can see, the point is to display the message "Use C-f!" in the echo area when the left arrowkey gets pressed. However, what this does is output the message into the current buffer I'm editing.

What am I missing?

Regards,

David Lind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind key to command:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<left>") (lambda () (interactive) (message "Use C-f!")))
```

Comment: Thank you sir! So the key has to be bound to a function? That's how I interpret this since the only thing different about my version and your is that your command is defined as a lambda function.

Comment: Not only a function, an interactive function.

Comment: But why does it have to be a lambda? I did the same thing just now to load a file upon entering haskell-mode.. `(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook (lambda () (load-file "~/yada.el")))` .. Trying without the lambda definition renders errors, isn't load-file considered a function by itself? Because `(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'load-file "~/yada.el")` fails. Perhaps this is the subject of another post? :)

Comment: @davidl `(load-file "~/yada.el")` and `(message "Use C-f!")` are function calls, not a functions.